# Как работает self в Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Как работает `self`?
Понял что метод `self` передает ссылку на сам себя, а вот в каких случаях использовать `self` а в каких нет я не понял...

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669527/use-of-ruby-self-keyword

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby - полностью объектно-ориентированный язык. В любой момент времени вы действуете в рамках какого-то объекта, даже если все выглядит так, что вы работаете вне объекта. В языке нет функций и процедур в привычном понимании, только методы, причем метод не может вызываться без получателя, т.е. объекта.

`self` - это ссылка на текущий объект. Для обращений к элементам интанс-объекта не обязательно указывать `self`, так как он подразумевается по умолчанию, но иногда он нужен. Например, при создании методов класса

```
class MyClass
  def hello
    p 'hello'
  end
end

o = MyClass.new
o.hello
# MyClass.hello - ошибка
```

Однако

```
class MyClass
  def self.hello
    p 'hello'
  end
end

MyClass.hello
o = MyClass.new
# o.hello - ошибка
```

Это не единственный случай, когда вы не сможете обойтись без `self`, однако чтобы всех их осветить потребуется небольшая книга. При работе с `self` главное помнить, что это ссылка на текущий объект и что такой объект всегда существует, даже когда вы работаете в корневой области видимости

```
self
=> main
```

Comment: А ещё `self` бывает необходим, чтобы вызвать у него сеттер, потому что без явного `self.` можно случайно задать локальную переменную в текущей области видимости.

Comment: "Функции и процедуры в привычном понимании" в Ruby есть: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/UnboundMethod.html

Comment: @Nakilon странное у вас "привычное понимание". `UnboundMethod` нельзя просто взять и вызвать, не привязав его к принимающему. И используются они в Ruby крайне редко и с довольно экзотическими целями вроде "пересадки методов" производительности ради. К функциям "в привычном понимании" ближе скорее `Proc`, и то это всего лишь объект с методом `call` и его синонимами.

Answer (score 1):

В другом ответе допущено несколько ошибок:

1. Для объявления метода класса вы "сможете обойтись без self", если вместо `def self.` напишете `def MyClass.`
2. `self` указывает не всегда на "текущий объект", а скорей на объект, в контексте которого интерпретатор выполняет [блок кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18153974/322020)

Более близок к нужному ответу был @D-side. Если есть локальная переменная под тем же именем, что и метод, происходит затенение, и для подсказки интерпретатору, что мы хотим именно метод, можно приписать `self.` слева, но и тут есть другой способ -- приписать `()` справа. Здесь иллюстрации и методы борьбы с такой "проблемой": https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-scope-in-ruby/

Comment: Строго говоря, ваше сообщение не является ответом - это комментарий. Кроме того, у вас в комментарии допущено ряд ошибок: 1. Вы никогда не сможете вызывать непривязанный метод 2. def MyClass объявляет инстанс-методы, речь шла о методах класса. У вас ошибочное утверждение. 3. Утверждение ошибочно, блок вообще не имеет отношение к self. Убедиться в присутствии текущего объекта вы всегда можете обратившись к self.

Comment: Первый пункт действительно являлся лишь комментарием -- теперь я его перенес куда положено. Остальное является ответом, т.к. непосредственно отвечает на вопрос о том, когда и почему нужен `self`. 2. проверил, ушло в `.singleton_methods` 3. по ссылке же показан пример блока в `class_eval`

Comment: @cheops 2. Скользкий момент! Смотря где. В контексте определения класса `self` это класс. Внутри инстанс-метода `self` это текущий объект. В зависимости от того, где определить метод (хотя определять методы внутри методов это безумие, это возможно), получатся синглтон-методы у разных объектов :)

Answer (score 0):

*Вставлю свои 5 копеек )*
*`self` в контексте метода*

```
def some_method
  self.some_other_method  # это self в контексте метода, он обращается к объекту
  # в отношении которого вызван метод someobj.some_method
  # т.е. self == someobj
end

def self.some_class_method  #это self в контексте класса он обращается к классу
  # т.е определяется метод класса который можно вызывать
  # используя имя класса SomeClass.some_class_method()
  # т.е. self == SomeClass <br></i>
end
```

p.s я вижу это так ) Если не прав исправляйте..